# Start an application at system start without login

Tags: server, scheduled-tasks, windows

We have a new server running and we got some new programs doing import routines. So far so good... But **there is one program that is put into autostart folder**. So **it doesn't run until admin logs in and it stops if we logout**.

I'd like to put this one into a seperate session so it may work without any interaction by simply starting it with the task scheduler at startup. Is this the right way to do this? Is it safe if I log in later and log out?

Many thanks!

**Edit**: The applications shows as a symbol in the task bar if running, it can be configured by this. Anything I must know about this if I change?

**Edit**: It is not my application, I cannot rewrite it as a service.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I successfully added the application by using task schelduler on startup. Login and logout will not quit the application but no symbol is shown. Please add details to my side questions and I'll mark your answer as the accepted one.

Edit: Ended up using this one. If I have to configure, I stop the application in task manager and start it again by link. After that I quit the application and restart it by task scheduler manual start.

Comment: Hi, have you also tried put the shortcut of your app inside windows startup folder  to let it auto run after reboot? If so, do you know if it will run without login?

Comment: Apps in your user startup folder won't start without login.

Answer (score 6):

You need to run your program as a Windows Service. One way of doing it is using the `sc.exe` program:

```
> sc create <new_service_name> binPath= "c:\myapp\myapp.exe"
```

You can read about it [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/251192).

Comment: We are running Server 20012 R2, what's the best way to do this?

Answer (score 5):

You need to separate your application in two.

To allow it to run without a user session, you need a windows service. That should handle all the background stuff. You can then register the service and set it to start when the system starts.

To allow it to have a UI, and show up in the notification area, you need a windows application. This will be in autostart as usual, and will communicate with the service - for example, over named pipes.

While it is still (barely) possible to run an UI application without a user session, it's only maintained for backwards compatibility, and already shows a lot of problems. It will likely be removed altogether in the future, because it breaks quite a few contracts. Do not rely on hacks like this.

Comment: It isn't my application and I cannot split it. I simply want the server to start the application without the admin to login

Comment: @Daniel That's too bad. You'll either have to keep someone logged in at all times, or you'll need to find a different application to handle the job.

Answer (score 2):

I also used the task scheduler to create the application at system startup. It should be noted that if you want to use for mining, you have to disable an option in "settings" where it says that if the application lasts more than three days in a row it will end.

[image: task manager settings]

It really works wonderfully!

Answer (score 1):

it is a old question but I recently solved in another way...

(before I was using a scheduled-task for startup but this gave me diverse problems with lots software...)

Some programs also for diverse reasons must be run at a user level... or even inside a specific user session...

So the best way I found was to use a tool like Sysinternal/Autoruns to program the auto-logon to a specific user (it is a registry setting)... and in the startup-folder of that user (or any other "autorun/autolaunch" task)... run a script that first locks the screen... and next runs the other intended programs... that will run under that user profile...

so you can choose a standard user or a administrator... or even launch programs from a standard user in adminsitrator mode...

I hope will help...
This "hack" solved me many problems with startup apps...

Comment: Won't do that on a customers server, but it works :)

Comment: I have develop some apps for my server but since years i had the problem that when the server goes down for a loss of power (very often), i was forced to restart SOME of my app MANUALLY. Also, i made another app JUST FOR check and notify me when this happen, so i can login and start them. All because i need to see the GUI of my app. So now i have tested what you wrote and BAAAM works like charm! Thanks! (stupid me to not think about this workaround). But, the only "bad" thing is that now i have my plain text password in the registry. Any solution for that?

Answer (score 1):

I have successfully started 3 console applications that depend on each other using Task Scheduler. One of the applications even has internet access. I did struggle to make it work, so here is my final solution (task properties):

- Create another User Account with a long random password and save it somewhere on your primary account. Be sure to secure questions too. Do not use real passwords: [link 1](https://www.top-password.com/knowledge/view-security-questions-and-answers-in-windows-10.html), [link 2](https://serverfault.com/a/797206).
- General:

  - Change the User Account to the previously created user.
  - Check: Whether user is logged on or not (needed when using system startup)
  - Uncheck: Do not store password. The task will only have access to local computer resources - This is required for internet access. Provide the random password that was generated earlier.
- Triggers:

  - Type: At system startup
  - Check: Delay task for 2 minutes (you can write custom time) (wait for Windows)
- Action:

  - Type: Start a program
  - Start in: Provide the working directory for your program (needed for relative paths)
- Settings:

  - Check: If the task fails, restart every (this helps if linked tasks start in the wrong order)
  - Uncheck: Stop the task if it runs longer than
- Power:

  - Uncheck: Start the task only if the computer is on AC power

Answer (score 0):

I could not get the "sc create" command to work. Instead I manually edited the registry using regedit. I added a new key in HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services.

I used the following page to figure out required parameters and their values. Note that the names do not map.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/install/inf-addservice-directive

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but for anyone that stumbles here.  Use srvany to set the program as a custom service.

Note that when you do this with for example dropbox, googledrive, etc., you will need stop the service, then open the program normally to make changes like password, updates, etc.

below is a well enough intro.

https://www.iceflatline.com/2015/12/run-a-windows-application-as-a-service-with-srvany/

Download the tool kit here

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=17657

Answer (score 0):

Convert user application to Service and Register it using **Regsvr32** or **installutil.exe**. It will start the service using  **SYSTEM** user account. Which is a high privilege account. 
Note : You can`t run any Window based application. Even a Message only window.