# Console app not launching via task scheduler when set to "At StartUp"

Tags: c#

I have implemented a simple console application in C#.Net that writes something to a text file in "C:\MyFolder" as soon as it launches. I have configured the application in task scheduler with the below properties.

```
General tab->Run whether user is logged on or not.
Triggers -> At system start up
Actions -> Program/Script = Path to my exe ( E:\MyProject\Test.exe)
           Start-in = Path with exe name . (E:\MyProject)
```

I am expecting  the text file to be present once I start my machine. That is before logging in to the desktop as I have set the property to "At system start up" rather than "At log on" . However only If I log in to the machine, my exe starts running and the file gets copied. Is it because it is a Console App which requires a Desktop/UI to launch.?

So how will be the case in server machines where we don't have a user login or it gets logged in by default.? How can I make my console application to lauch/ or work in background even before login/ where there is no login?

Please clarify!!

Thanks

Comment: It did not work since your program is not a script running in the background. Refer: https://serverfault.com/questions/848968/task-scheduler-scheduled-task-at-startup-not-working

Comment: Create a windows service instead of a console app.  This answer applies to your situation.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/31857949/1563833

Answer (score 1):

Running console applications do indeed work via the task scheduler. I use several of them in our corporate environment to do some file level tasks that VB/BAT just aren't fun for. You just need to make sure that you have it set to "Run whether user is logged on or not" and ensure that the user you select has appropriate permissions (e.g. if you're connecting to a FileShare to do tasks, ensure the user launching the application has access to the NFS, SAMBA store, etc). Also check the event log for an .NET errors, as well as the task history in the Task Scheduler.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

The above is just an FYI, but since you've already checked that - I would add some logging into your console application. Have it write to a text file in the same directory as the EXE and then output any application errors via that way to see if it's launching and having an issue continuing with something (e.g. the permissions issue, etc).

Comment: My consoleapp runs when I set to "At log on" rather than "At system start up". I have tried adding logging as well as event viewer logging too, but it seems the console app itelf is not getting launched unless I log to windows using my credentials. In my case I have only started my computer but not logged in. And for permission, I have set SYSTEM which in turn has permissions to my folder

Answer (score 1):

For me, the issue is because of relative paths. task ran successfully but I can't see any logs. I changed to absolute paths and it solved my issue.